# Should we need to read the file to upload it via LibCurl (C++)?

Tags: c++, libcurl

I have a file name temp.txt. `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, {});`
The third parameter has to be a char*.

- Is reading the whole file the only way or can we do it another way?
- If there is another way should we bother about setting boundary ('multipart/form')

Comment: There are several [examples](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html) on [libcurl's website](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl) showing how to upload files. Have you looked at any of them yet?

Comment: I went through few examples and figured out only a way. Most of the file upload examples refer to PHP

Comment: PHP is used on many websites. But the HTTP examples are not specific to PHP.